# how to insert excel sheet into sql server and how to retrieve the data from it not the total excel sheet?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2005

hi i have a excel sheet with 500 rows,i want to upload that sheet on server and insert it data to sqlserver ,and i have created the table with name as excel having the same columns as excel sheet,the data need to be store into this table while uploading a excel sheet,and when i want to retrieve only one row i want to display that row only,how it is possible,can any one please tell me?and i dont want use ms access and oledb connection,i have used Sql server 2005 in my project..
i tried like this,please tell me where is the mistake...........

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            String strConnection = "user id=sa;pssword=E@2013;Data Source=EKTHA-3D34;Initial Catalog=Ektha;Integrated Security=True";

                  string path = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;
                         //Create connection string to Excel work book
                 // string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
                  string excelConnectionString = "user id=sa;password=E@2013;Data Source=EKTHA-3D34;Persist Security Info=False";
                     //Create Connection to Excel work book
                     SqlConnection excelConnection =new SqlConnection(excelConnectionString);
                      //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
                      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]",excelConnection);
                     excelConnection.Open();
                      SqlDataReader dReader;
                        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
                       //Give your Destination table name
                        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "PayDescription";
                          sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                         excelConnection.Close();
                         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to struggle that much. Keep first row as columns which you want in table. then convert you excel sheet to xls(97-2003) format. Right click on your database task-> import->clickNext->select datasource microsoft excel and check first row as column. Give next.confirm authentication give next,next,in grid you check second row and go for edit select proper datatype. then continue. the table is imported in database. Just rename that as you need.